# How to hash strings of chars and integers in hash table

Tags: string, hash

I am trying to hash strings names containing 2 letters and 4 digit.
for example the names (strings):
AZ5466
GE1890
RU0291

and save them in a hash table.

I thought if there is a way to refer the string as integer number, then i can easily make:
(name % 10) - for example
and hash them in array size 10 of linked lists.

Using C language.

Comment: What language are you using? What did you try?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: I tried using atoi, but from what i understood it is good only fr numbers and not for chars, i tried also casting to integer, but it give every time the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert each character to its ascii code and multiply.

For example, in your case, you can  write the something like:

```
int number = ((name[0] - 'A') * ('Z' - 'A' + 1) + (name[1] - 'A')) * 10000 + atoi(name + 2);
```

The code assumes that all the letters are capital.

By the way, you should check if converting to integer and then modulo something is good enough for you (you need to make sure that you'll have approximatelly the same number of elements in each bucket).

If you want, you can split them much more easily by the first or any letter:

```
hash = (name[0] - 'A')
```

will give you a number between 0 and 25 (according to the first letter), and

```
hash = (name[5] - '0')
```

will give you the same results as converting to integer (the way I've suggested) and then perform modulo 10.

Comment: You'r the KING! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use elf_hash, or you can rewrite it in the language you are working in.
    
    `unsigned long elf_hash(const char *name);`